# pangram problem from exorcism.io, python track, why doesn't my solution work?

Tags: python, pangram

```
def is_pangram(sentence):
    alf = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    for x in alf:
        if x not in sentence:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

My code is failing to return True in every case it should.

I am using mentored mode on exercism.io, but the python track is oversubscribed and only provides feedback on the major exercises.

I'm hoping a python wizard here can point me towards my errors. Thanks much....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is to check if the sentence contains *all* letters of the alphabet. So while you can determine that is **not** the case (i.e. `return false`) when you find the *first* letter that is not in the sentence, you cannot state the opposite (i.e. `return true`) until you have checked *all* the letters.

```
def is_pangram(sentence):
    alf = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    for x in alf:
        if x not in sentence:
            return False
    return True
```

---

**Addendum**: 
There is also the python-only, little known and seldom used `for/else` language feature [see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops): `for` loops may have an `else` clause which is called when the loop exits "normally" (i.e. with out stopping early due to a `break`, `return` or exception). This makes the following code a viable alternative. Note the different indentation of the `else` clause when compared with the OP code.

```
def is_pangram(sentence):
    alf = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    for x in alf:
        if x not in sentence:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: That was it. Thank for taking the time to answer my question. :)